# Angular 2 reactive form validation for non mandatory field

Tags: angular2-forms

I am working on reactive form like In my reactive form having 3 fields but in which 2 are mandatory and one is non mandatory but it has validation like if user enter a string in respective field it has minimum character limit example 10 character. but i faced issue when user has enter string it is showing error but submit button is not going to disable.

```js
return FormBuilder.group({
      'surveyDueDate': ['', Validators.required],
      'rfsDueDate': [null, Validators.required],
      'comment': [null]
    });
```

```html
   <form (ngSubmit)="submit(form)" #form="ngForm">
<div>
    Survey date:
    <input name="surveyDueDate" [(ngModel)]="surveyDueDate">
</div>
<div>
    Due Date :  
    <input name="rfsDueDate" [(ngModel)]="rfsDueDate">
</div>
<div>
    Gift shipping address:
    <input name="comment">
</div>

<button type="submit" [disabled]="form.invalid">Register now!</button>
</form>
```

```
thanks in advance.
```

Answer (score 1):

In your component listen for the particular field changes. For example,

```
this.form.controls["comment"].valueChanges().subscribe((commentValue)=>{
  if(commentValue && commentValue.length>10 && this.form.invalid===false){
  this.form.controls["comment"].setErrors({invalid:true});
} else {
  this.form.controls["comment"].setErrors(null);
  }
});
```